# I am parsing a file using DOM and want to send it to table view

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

I am new developing on Android and really stuck here.

I want to do the following:

- Parse xml file from internet using dom method [Found out how to do that using the example from that site http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser ]
- Send the information into a table layout
- While the information is on the table want to make it clickable using the flipper animation and seperate the information into two pages

Example: I am parsing titles and body info. The title have to be on the table layout and when you click each of the title to use the flipper info and corresponding to present its associate body info that you parsed.

The problem I have is how to manipulate the information after is parsed and handled it around.

Help!

Comment: i suggest avoiding XML if you can! use JSON.  There are some great libraries out there for parsing JSON like GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/  XML is a pain in the butt, especially if you're new

Comment: Check out this blog;
[p-xr.com](http://www.p-xr.com)
Try the source code below on the site. Very ease & understandable code..

Comment: I am parsing using DOM method and want to send the info on a table layout. Each cell become a link that when you click and by using the flipper function goes to next page where the other parced information is presented. Unfortunately, I am not very strong with Java and I have hard time to understand how to use the listview example and especially hot to use the array and manage the information:(

Answer (score 0):

To get started you should probably look into [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). That example shows how to back a `ListView` with an array of strings. You should be able to adapt that to use your parsed data.